# Update Android App on Google Play after it has been removed

Tags: android, google-play-console

How can I update my Android app on Google Play Console after it has been removed by Google for violating permission policies? Is there any way? I mistakenly ignored the emails sent by them for updating the app before the 9th of March.
Here are screenshots of my google play console
[image: ss1 of my google play console screen]

[image: ss2 of my google play console screen]

[image: ss3 of my google play console screen]

[image: ss4 of my google play console screen]

Comment: Aren't you getting the option to re submit the app with necessary changes?

Comment: can you show the screen shots of your google play console account?

Comment: Yes.. I've added now. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can see the reason or policy violation in play console. I think it's under alert options in Play console. please check it, correct it in the app. then update your version code and version name, the sign your app, publish it again. Go to your app in play console, then select App releases under Release management then click manage in production -> create release or publish it as beta, after get approved from play console, publish it as production.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've removed the SEND_SMS permission from my app but Google Play Console is not allowing me to update the app. It is asking to choose one of the options provided in Permissions Declaration Form. There is no option that says "No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy". I've also added a screenshot of my google play console screen.

Comment: @PranjaliSoni Can I know all options in permission Declaration Form, I can see only four options in the screenshot, You should choose one of the option in that.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Choose one of the options from Permissions Declaration Form or report a new use case and accept the declarations, both are mandatory @PranjaliSoni

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Few of my apps which were using SEND_SMS permissions have been removed from playstore. Now you can do two things:

1. If your app relies on SEND_SMS permission for it's working, then you need to submit a permission declaration form with relevant information. [Find it here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en)
2. Remove these permissions if are not very much needed, then simply upload your app to playstore.

You'll be guided for the same when you'll push a new update on Google play console.

Comment: I've removed the SEND_SMS permission from my app but Google Play Console is not allowing me to update the app. It is asking to choose one of the options provided in Permissions Declaration Form. There is no option that says "No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy".

Comment: Ok, Do you have CALL_PHONE or READ_PHONE_STATE permissions in your app? Could you please share manifest screenshot here.

Comment: Problem Solved. I took help of Google chat support, they guided me how to resolve this issue. Thank you ..

Comment: @PranjaliSoni how did you solved this? Can you please explain it.